# How can I make my PokerHand class randomly deal a thousand hands?

Tags: poker

```
public class PokerHand
{
    // ArrayList for cards
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;

    /**
     * Constructor for class Pokerhand
     */
    public PokerHand()
    {
         cards = new ArrayList<Card>(); // arrayList of cards

    }
    /**
     * Add cards to list
     */
    public void addCard(Card card1, Card card2, Card card3)
    {
        cards.add(card1);
        cards.add(card2);
        cards.add(card3);
    }         
}
```

This is my Card Class

```
public class Card()
{
    private int value;
    private int suit;

    private static String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    private static String[] values  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                                       "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    public static  String valueAsString( int value ) {
        return values[value];
    }

    Card(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.value=value;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public  String toString()
    {
          return values[value] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    public int getValue() {
         return value;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

How can I deal a 1000 three card hands? I am stuck on how a variety of things, including what additional methods I need. How can I construct a deal method and how can I make the deal method dish out a thousand random hands while shuffling every time a hand is dealt?

Comment: Unless your deck has 3000 cards, you need to add something like a "Game" type that includes a certain amount of players that each get a hand.  Each game would have it's own deck instance...

Comment: So basically I should add an arrayList of Game which shows each hand being dealt?

Comment: Basically.  I would construct Game() in a way that you can do things like Game.PlayerList() and Game.Deal() in which all the players in the PlayersList are dealt a hand.

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22945816/1653609) help? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

All of these are implementations are based on code from [my card library](https://github.com/FracturedRetina/All-In/).

### Shuffle

```
public Card[] shuffle(Card[] deck) {
    Random gen = new Random();
    boolean[] added = new boolean[deck.length];
    int positionToAdd = gen.nextInt(deck.length);
    Card[] newDeck = new Card[deck.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        while (newDeck[i] == null) {
            if (!added[positionToAdd]) {
                newDeck[i] = deck[positionToAdd];
                positionToAdd = gen.nextInt(deck.length);
                added[i] = true;
            } else {
                positionToAdd = gen.nextInt(deck.length);
            }
        }
    }


    return newDeck;
}
```

### Implementation

```
ArrayList<Card> dealFrom = new ArrayList<Card>();
PokerHand[] hands = new PokerHand[1000];
/*Populate the "dealFrom" yourself here*/

dealFrom = Array.asList(shuffle(dealFrom.toArray()));

for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i += 3) {
    //Write your deal method here
    hands[i] = new PokerHand(dealFrom[i], dealFrom[i + 1], dealFrom[i + 2]);
}
```

Hope this helps.